# Android - Add button after tabhost not showing in every tab

Tags: android, button, tabs

So i wanted to have a bottom button so that it shows in all tabs, but i cant seem to make it available at the bottom of every tab screen. I only have the first tab filled with edit text elements and spinners. But the button doesnt show even after setting a scrollview since all elements take more than the screen size. Heres the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TabHost 
    android:id="@+id/personalfiletab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="56dp">
           <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
              <TableLayout 
               android:id="@+id/pessoal_tab"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
      <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/ecra_editpersonalfile_infoform" />
     </TableLayout>
     <TableLayout android:id="@+id/morada__contacto_tab"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
      <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/ecra_editpersonalfile_moradacontactoform" />
     </TableLayout>
      <TableLayout 
               android:id="@+id/profissional_tab"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
      <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/ecra_editpersonalfile_infoproform" />
     </TableLayout>
      <TableLayout 
               android:id="@+id/documentacao_tab"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
      <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/ecra_editpersonalfile_documentacaoform" />
     </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView> 
         </FrameLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>  
  <Button
   android:text="submit"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/submitprofileButton">     
   </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the button doesnt show at the bottom of the screen in every tab...

Comment: Based on this layout, you only have one tab, since you only have one immediate child of the `FrameLayout`. Hence, the button is showing at the bottom of every tab.